# What can be used to change the direction of the laser beam?

Tags: optics, reflection, mirror-symmetry

Let's say we have a laser beam coming from a source called X, we would like to change its direction so that it would hit directly on the object that we have. What would be the possible solutions?

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution is to point the laser at a plane mirror, angled so that the beam reflects off it, on to the object. With an ordinary, cheap, metal-backed glass mirror, you'll lose perhaps 10% of the light intensity; and as well as the main beam, reflected off the backing, you'll get a fainter beam, slightly displaced, reflected off the front of the glass. If the laser is *very* bright you could 'burn off' the metal backing where the beam hits it.

If the laser beam *is* very bright, or if the defects mentioned earlier must be avoided, you could use, instead of a mirror, a glass prism in total internal reflecting mode. The shape of prism to choose depends on the angle through which you want to deflect the beam.